# Link to other section in the same page not working

Tags: html

I want to link a button to a div component below in the same page.

I want to link to div id 'abc' but it seems not working. I have checked the id with href and it is the same. I don't know why it's not working.

```html
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="#abc" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">
                            <i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i>
                            <span>Add new course</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

<p style="height:1000px">space</p>

        <div id="abc" class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">
                            Add Course
                        </h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                            &times;
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Subject</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Time start</label>
                            <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<p style="height:1000px">space</p>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Works there. Do you have more than one `id="abc"` ? Also it looks like you have some kind of framework like bootstrap - is that correct?

Comment: What is the meaning of "not working" here? Do you get some errors in the console? Is it jumping somewhere else? Is it opening a new tab? Little unicorns attack the div? What happens?

Comment: it did not jump to any section. And yes, I use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my test snippet works too...

```html
<div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 6000px">
    <a href="#abc" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i>
        <span>Add new course</span>
    </a>
</div>


<div id="abc" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                        Add Course
                    </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        &times;
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subject</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Time start</label>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code snippet works but when I copy it to my website it got the same problems (did not appear modal). I think it happens because I implement Bootstrap v4.3.1 or jQuery.